# livy throwing error in batchmode Error: Only local python files are supported: Parsed arguments

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I tried executing **livy** in batch mode by submiting a python file but it doesnt work, i tried 2 ways -

1. Run the **py** file from local file system & also
2. run it on hdfs by copying it there ... but its not working...

please help

```
hduser@tarun-ubuntu:/home/tarun/spark/examples/src/main/python$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"  tarun-ubuntu:8998/batches --data '{"file": "file:///home/tarun/spark/examples/src/main/python/pi.py", "name": "pipy", "executorCores":1, "executorMemory":"512m", "driverCores":1, "driverMemory":"512m", "queue":"default", "args":["10"]}'

"requirement failed: Local path /home/tarun/spark/examples/src/main/python/pi.py cannot be added to user sessions."
```

so i moved **pi.py** to hdfs at livy atleast accepted the curl call:

```
hduser@tarun-ubuntu:/home/tarun/spark/examples/src/main/python$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"  tarun-ubuntu:8998/batches --data '{"file": "/pi.py", "name": "pipy", "executorCores":1, "executorMemory":"512m", "driverCores":1, "driverMemory":"512m", "queue":"default", "args":["10"]}'
{"id":20,"state":"running","appId":null,"appInfo":{"driverLogUrl":null,"sparkUiUrl":null},"log":[]}
```

But when i checked the logs :

```
$ curl tarun-ubuntu:8998/batches/20/log | python -m json.tool  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1415  100  1415    0     0   186k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  197k
{
    "from": 0,
    "id": 20,
    "log": [
        "Error: Only local python files are supported: Parsed arguments:",
        "  master                  local",
        "  deployMode              client",
        "  executorMemory          512m",
        "  executorCores           1",
        "  totalExecutorCores      null",
        "  propertiesFile          /home/tarun/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf",
        "  driverMemory            512m",
        "  driverCores             1",
        "  driverExtraClassPath    null",
        "  driverExtraLibraryPath  null",
        "  driverExtraJavaOptions  null",
        "  supervise               false",
        "  queue                   default",
        "  numExecutors            null",
        "  files                   null",
        "  pyFiles                 null",
        "  archives                null",
        "  mainClass               null",
        "  primaryResource         hdfs://localhost:54310/pi.py",
        "  name                    pipy",
        "  childArgs               [10]",
        "  jars                    null",
        "  packages                null",
        "  packagesExclusions      null",
        "  repositories            null",
        "  verbose                 false",
        "",
        "Spark properties used, including those specified through",
        " --conf and those from the properties file /home/tarun/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf:",
        "  spark.driver.memory -> 512m",
        "  spark.executor.memory -> 512m",
        "  spark.driver.cores -> 1",
        "  spark.master -> local",
        "  spark.executor.cores -> 1",
        "",
        "    .primaryResource",
        "Run with --help for usage help or --verbose for debug output"
    ],
    "total": 38
}

curl tarun-ubuntu:8998/batches/20 | python -m json.tool  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   482  100   482    0     0   105k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  117k
{
    "appId": null,
    "appInfo": {
        "driverLogUrl": null,
        "sparkUiUrl": null
    },
    "id": 20,
    "log": [
        "Spark properties used, including those specified through",
        " --conf and those from the properties file /home/tarun/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf:",
        "  spark.driver.memory -> 512m",
        "  spark.executor.memory -> 512m",
        "  spark.driver.cores -> 1",
        "  spark.master -> local",
        "  spark.executor.cores -> 1",
        "",
        "    .primaryResource",
        "Run with --help for usage help or --verbose for debug output"
    ],
    "state": "dead"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error `Only local python files are supported` is most likely being thrown by Spark because Livy is appending an HDFS prefix to your file path by default.

Two things you should try:

1. Add the directory you want to read your py file from to the `livy.file.local-dir-whitelist` setting in `livy.conf`. According to the comment in the conf file the application "can only reference remote URIs when starting their sessions." This is most likely why Livy is defaulting to HDFS when you submit the job.
2. When you pass the `file` parameter to the REST API use just one slash after `file:/`. For example, `{"file": "file:/home/tarun/spark/examples/src/main/python/pi.py"}`. I believe this is the correct syntax.

One thing to [be aware of](https://github.com/cloudera/livy/blob/b75bc11b65f72414607458e659d23f00990c6747/python-api/src/main/python/livy/client.py#L157) when running in cluster mode:

> Note that the URL should be reachable by the Spark driver process. If running the driver in cluster mode, it may reside on a different host, meaning "file:" URLs have to exist on that node (and not on the client machine).

In other words you might need to have a copy of your py file on every node in the cluster in order to ensure the driver can read the file.

Hope that helps.